# Bind two function to same button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It's valid to do something like:

```
<form id="legalopt">
    <button type="submit" id="confirmopt" onclick="function2();">Click ME!</button>
</form>

$('#legalopt').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    function1();
}
```

As you can see, `funcion1()` is fired when the form is submitted by the submit button and also `function2()` is called because the `onlick` call of the button.

Is this valid? Is cross-browser compatible?

Comment: Why not simply add both functions to the submit callback?

Comment: nothing wrong with that - but you can also bind two function on to the button itself as well right after: function1(); function2();

Comment: Can you please explain, what you want to achieve?

Comment: Of course I can call just one function and then inside of it put function1 and 2, im just asking for curiosity if this scheme is valid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would prefer ,Since they both are executing at same time,

```
$('#legalopt').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  function2();
  function1();
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that 1 goes before 2?

Comment: @Johan `1 goes before 2`  confuses,but OP should decide,which he needs to call first.

Comment: What I'm asking is: Are you sure that the `onclick` property fires before the `submit` callback? Otherwise it might be `function2(); function1();` and not `function1();function2();`

Comment: @Johan I'm pretty sure he is suggesting to NOT use an inline-event handler at all. But anyway, inline-event handlers are fired very first (before any DOM Level 3 handlers)

Comment: Yes,I believe that the click triggers first and then submit.Will edit the post :) my intention is to do the functions at same place by deciding the order of execution op wants :)

Comment: @jAndy Ah ok. I'm asking because he's rewriting OP's code while intending to keep the old functionality.

Comment: Of course I can call just one function and then inside of it put function1 and 2, im just asking for curiosity if this scheme is valid

Comment: @DomingoSL Yes,you can do it,as per your interest.But it is not a recommended way.For sure it creates mess in future(especially for new bies who is looking in to your code).Don't go for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute function in order then it will be nice to pass the function as argument to the function which is to be called first.

```
function1(function2);
...
// At the end of function1's code
function2();
```

Answer (score -1):

Whoever voted down my answer, here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/5d7bG/)

```
<form id="legalopt">
  <button type="submit" id="confirmopt" onclick="function1();function2();">Click ME!</button>
</form>

<div id="box"></div>


#box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 150px;
  left: 12px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}



$(function() {

  $('#legalopt').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    function1();
    function2();
  });

  function function1() {
    $('#box').stop().animate({ left: '250px' }, 600);
  }
  function function2() {
    $('#box').css({ background: '#900' }).animate({ left: '12px'}, 600);
  }

});
```